# Change Console and repo browser certificate for Collabnet svnedge

Tags: ssl-certificate, svn, jetty, subversion-edge, collabnet

I need to change ssl certificate for our collabnet svn edge console and repo browser. I came across few documentations for changing ssl on console by creating new svnedge.jks file and replacing it with old one in csvn/appserver/etc/ directory, but whenever I do it svn edge consoled doesn't start. It gives below error

"WARNING: CSVN Console timed-out waiting for http://localhost:3343/csvn"

Answer (score 0):

you have to change to https and access throw https://localhost:4434/csvn/